# Webdriver Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, web, xpath

hello colleagues a question, how would I click a href="javascript:void(0)" I have been trying to understand the same question from the same forum but I do not try to understand it very well, I await your contributions
the xpath href => //*[@id="course-link-_62332_1"] ,
the xpath h4 = //*[@id="course-link-_62332_1"]/h4
here photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2geI.jpg)

Comment: how about `find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="javascript:void(0)"]').click()`. If you want better help then create better question - with minimal working code and with real URL which we could test in web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
driver.find_element_by_id('course-link-_62332_1').click()
```

Comment: thanks for you help , I didn't see the id element and I also have to take into account the server's response

Answer (score 0):

`href="javascript:void(0)"` is used to make the browser stay on same page when clicked. It might be performing task/event which is defined in JavaScript/Jquery script or so.
Coming to your question you can click on href by this method.

```
element1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="course-link-_62332_1"]')
element2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="course-link-_62332_1"]/h4 ')
element1.click()
element2.click()
```